# How do you start the user's selected Daydream programmatically?

Tags: android, screensaver

On my Galaxy Nexus, I can tap this button in system preferences to start my currently selected daydream.

[image: preferences screenshot]

Is there a way to reproduce this functionality in an app via Intent?  I don't have a daydream service, but I would like to allow the user to start their preferred daydream.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

- Edit 9/22/2014: This does not work on some Samsung phones
  I figured out how to do this by digging through some Android source code.

```
final Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
intent.setClassName("com.android.systemui", "com.android.systemui.Somnambulator");
startActivity(intent);
```

[Sample app available here](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.trolldad.daydream.launcher).

Comment: This doesn't work in Android 13 (Pixel) anymore. com.android.systemui is crashing when trying to start this activity.

Answer (score 0):

Using adb

> adb shell am start -n com.android.systemui/.Somnambulator