# Daydream service : make custom Daydream service as default

Tags: android, daydream, dreamservice

I created a Daydream service, and it's work perfectly, but I want to make it as default (don't need to go to Setting /screen saver ...). Is there a way to set screen saver default package like `setDefaultComponent` (`packageName`,`serviceClassName`)?

**RetailService**:
[image: RetailService]

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to change the default daydream of User forcefully, rather; you can navigate the user to a particular setting page so that the user can make that decision. The default setting is something sensitive, and leaving the decision to the User is the only way and the right approach. For opening the particular setting page please refer below answer.

[Opening daydream setting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20648305/in-android-how-to-change-the-settings-of-daydream-from-code)

Comment: In rooted device you can give it a try. Please refer the link. It may be of some help to you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7392067/android-changing-the-system-settings-of-a-rooted-device-from-inside-the-app